# Footnote rule appears where not wanted

Tags: rules

Using LyX, I have a strange problem with footnote rules that appear when there is
 no footnote beneath them. This happens when there is a footnote in the
 left-hand column on a two-column page and a figure in the right-hand
 column. This causes a footnote rule to appear at the bottom of the
 following page, even if it's not a multicol page. The unwanted rule disappears if the figure on the previous
 page is deleted.
 My question is does anyone know of a way I can have the footnote and
 the figure without the unwanted rule?

Comment: It is in your best interest that you post a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: This does not seem like normal behavior.  Try removing packages one at a time until the problem goes away.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to post the LyX MWE file. I've decided to eliminate the rule altogether, and now I actually prefer not having it, but would be willing to continue to investigate this problem if anyone is interested.